# Variable scope and get_varible

Tags: tensorflow

Why I can't get the result of 100, but a random number? Code is below:

```
def func1():
    with tf.variable_scope("var_scope"):
        v1 = tf.get_variable('var1', shape=[])
        v1 = tf.zeros([1])
        v1 = v1 + 100

def func2():
    with tf.variable_scope("var_scope", reuse=True):
        v2 = tf.get_variable('var1')

        with tf.Session() as sess:
            sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            result = sess.run(v2)
            print(result)

func1()
func2()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write

```
v1 = tf.get_variable('var1', shape=[])
```

... in `func1`, this variable gets initialized randomly. Subsequent ops in `func1` do not change this node, but define *new* nodes. Remember there's a difference between python variable and tensorflow node in the computational graph.

Change the code to

```
v1 = tf.get_variable('var1', shape=[], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0))
```

... to see the difference.